# React Component properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to use a component property *this.albumButtons* to store an array of AlbumButtons.

When *componentDidMount* gets called, I fetch the album names and set it to the state.  Then, I call makeButtons from the names.

In my makeButtons function, I set this.albumButtons to the array of AlbumButton components.

When I check *this.albumButtons* length, I get 0.

What am I doing wrong?

```
export default class ModalContent extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      albumNames: [],
      isLoading: false,
      isEmptyOfAlbums: false,
    }
    this.albumButtons = []
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({isLoading: true})
    const getAlbumsNamesPromise = new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
      MySwiftClass.getAlbumsNames((arr) => {
        if(arr.length === 0) this.setState({isEmptyOfAlbums: true});
        this.setState({albumNames: arr})
      })
    })
    getAlbumsNamesPromise.then(this.makeButtons).then(this.setState({isLoading: false})) 
  }

  makeButtons() {
    //const component = this;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.albumButtons = this.state.names.map((name) =>
        <AlbumButton
          key={name}
          name={name}
        />
      )
      resolve()
    })
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading){
      return(
      //loading screen
      )
    }
    return(
    <Text>{this.albumButtons.length}</Text>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous, you need to `resolve` in the callback of setState so it waits until state is updated with the albumNames:

```
const getAlbumsNamesPromise = new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
  MySwiftClass.getAlbumsNames((arr) => {
    if(arr.length === 0) this.setState({isEmptyOfAlbums: true});
    this.setState({albumNames: arr}, resolve)
  })
}) // also need to pass a function into .then, not invoke a function
getAlbumsNamesPromise.then(this.makeButtons).then(() => this.setState({isLoading: false}))
```

Your also mapping over `this.state.names.map` I think you meant `this.state.albumNames.map`

Comment: Thank you! As an aside, when I passed this.makeButtons as a callback, I had to bind it to the current scope or use an arrow function (e) => this.makeButtons(e).  What is e in this context?

Comment: `e` would be whatever you pass into `resolve()`. You can also keep it how it is and change `makeButtons() {` to `makeButtons = () => {`

Comment: which is best practice?

Comment: either way is fine, personally I just always do `makeButtons = () => {`